# How Can i Use The Values Of The Int in The Scanner

Tags: java

```
            int CMC = 279;
            int BDM = 326;
            int CP = 177;
            int CB =  228;
            int CR = 190;
            int PC = 43;
            int CCS = 24;
            int CE = 26;
            int FM = 20;
            int originalpricebake ;

            Scanner bakeorder1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int order1;             
            System.out.print("\nEnter Your 1st Item Order:");
            order1 = bakeorder1.nextInt();
            Scanner bakeorder2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int order2;             
            System.out.print("\nEnter Your 2nd Item Order:");
            order2 = bakeorder2.nextInt();
            Scanner bakeorder3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int order3;             
            System.out.print("\nEnter Your 3rd Item Order:");
            order3 = bakeorder3.nextInt();
            Scanner bakeorder4 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int order4;             
            System.out.print("\nEnter Your 4th Item Order:");
            order4 = bakeorder4.nextInt();
            Scanner bakeorder5 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int order5;             
            System.out.print("\nEnter Your 5th Item Order:");
            order5 = bakeorder5.nextInt();

            originalpricebake = order1 + order2 + order3 + order4 + order5;
            System.out.print("\nThe Current Price: " + originalpricebake);
```

how can i use the integer values on the top when i scan for an user input for his order? So that when i got the user input an equation will be made at the bottom of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Array to store the values and access it using loop.

```
    int order;
    int price=0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter how many orders: ");
    order = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

     //Create an integer array to store the input

    int bakeorder[] = new int[order];
    //int originalbakeprice[] = new int[order];
    for(int i=0;i<order;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the order " + (i+1) + " : ");
            bakeorder[i] = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
             price +=bakeorder[i];
    }
            System.out.println(price);
```

Comment: surely you mean `String bakeorder[] = new String[order];`

Comment: This is a better approach to use like:     String bakeorder[] = new String[order];

Comment: What Should I Write So That i Can Get the Summation Of  All The Orders The User Wrote? Here Is The Prices And Its Variable:                 
            int CMC = 279;
            int BDM = 326;
            int CP = 177;
            int CB =  228;
            int CR = 190;
            int PC = 43;
            int CCS = 24;
            int CE = 26;
            int FM = 20;

Comment: Consider edited code and create array for values instead of hard code the values. e.g,   String selection[]= {"CMC","BDM","CP","CB","CR","PC","CCS","CE","FM"};
        int values[]= {279, 326,177,228,190,43,24,26,20};                                            or you can use 2D arrays for these values.